# What is the difference between \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} and \usepackage{geometry}, \geometry{margin= 1in}?

Tags: formatting, geometry

I would like to know the difference between this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
```

and:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{margin=1in}
```

Comment: at first glance I would assume that it gives the same output. Do you see a difference?

Comment: You haven't indicated whether or not the instruction `\geometry{margin=1in}` is supposed to occur in the preamble -- or whether it might occur somewhere in the body of the document. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mico Preamble to both, sorry!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't see any difference either. But why these two different methods exist if they are to give the same output anyway?

Comment: Why not? I prefer the second method but other people prefer to set options when loading the package

Comment: this is quite common eg hyperref allows (some) options on `\usepackage` but has a more general `\hypersetup` that can be used after the package is loaded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, I see. Thank you!